# jQuery to check amount

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery event to check if amount enter is less then or equal to zero. If true clear the entered amount. 
 But after after my event completion another event is running for that element which is setting default amount value to zero. Can anyone please tell me how do I stop any second event after completion of my event. 
I have tried using

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

but no success yet.

here is my code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[id^="amount_totalPaymentAmout"]', function(event) {
    var paymentAmount = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ""));
    if (paymentAmount <= 0) {
        $.sticky("Total payment amounts entered should be greater then Zero.", {
            autoclose: 2000,
            position: "top-right",
            type: "st-error"
        });
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: use return false; to stop

Comment: tried that,still not working

Comment: show updated code, where did u put return false

Comment: $(document).on('change','input[id^="amount_totalPaymentAmout"]',function(event) {
  var paymentAmount=parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g ,""));
  if(paymentAmount<=0){
   $.sticky("Total payment amounts entered should be greater then Zero.", {
    autoclose : 2000,
    position : "top-right",
    type : "st-error"
   });
   $(this).val('');
   $(this).focus();
   
   return false;
   
  } 
  
  });

Comment: Can you a) Update the original post with updated code (Its near on impossible to read code in comments and b) Include the code for the other handler which is affecting this.

Comment: @Jamiec i have update my code,

Comment: @amritchhetri you've done a) not b)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
$(document).on("blur", "#yourid", function(e) {
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    if(myVal <= 0){
        alert('amount is less');
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can rely on HTML5 new field 'number'

```
<input type="number" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="64">
```

Edit :

I tried this piece of code and it works. Basically, I want the same thing as you do, conditions on the event.

I have two buttons, one has only the loader class, the other has the class and an id. 
If I click on the loader class, the event is launched. But if I click on the button with the id I want the event to launch only if the checkbox is checked, if not, I want an alert box to show and stop all events.

`e.stopImmediatePropagation();` does the trick

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="check_cgv"><label for="check_cgv">Checkbox text</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white loader">CLASS EVENT</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white loader" id="form-submit">CLASS AND ID EVENT</button>

<script>
         $(document).on({
               click: function (e) {
                 if(!$('#check_cgv').is(':checked')){ //if not checked
                   e.preventDefault(); // stop default behaviour
                   e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // stop all other events
                   alert('Event 1 launched, event 2 blocked');         
                 }
               }
         }, '#form-submit');

         $(document).on({
           click: function (e) {
             alert('Event 2 launched');
           }
         }, '.loader');
</script>
```

This will work as long as the code blocking the event is declare above the event you want to block.

Comment: Why downvote this answer ? The question is to use jquery to achieve what can be done in plain html. What i can see from the jquery posted is not very complicated, so why not doing it in html ?

Comment: This does not answer the question, re-read it. (Specifically, the OP's code has a second event handler which is affecting their jQuery, OP displays a specific message when validation is not met. OP resets value to empty when validation not met. Just throwing some html5 element at the problem does not even come close to answering their question)

Answer (score -1):

```
    //try below code 

    $("input[id^='amount_totalPaymentAmout']").on('keyup', function(event) {
      var paymentAmount = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ""));
          if (!paymentAmount > 0 ) {
            $.sticky("Total payment amounts entered should be greater then Zero.", {
              autoclose: 2000,
              position: "top-right",
              type: "st-error"
            });
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).focus();

          }
      });
```

Comment: @miriyaalnaresh actually if i use this event without DOM ,then it will only work for single row. i more then one rows with same field and the validation should work for every row.

Comment: What did you actually change here, except making the boolean logic just wrong? (`!paymentAmount > 0` will not do what you think it does)